# What is the name of consort for Narasimha avatar?

Tags: narasimha

Do Narasimha avatar of Vishnu has any wife? If yes, what is the name of the wife of Narasimha?

Comment: He did not had any consort.

Answer (score 4):

I am writing this brief answer based on [**Pancaratra**](https://www.wisdomlib.org/definition/nrisimha#pancaratra) tradition of Vaishnavism. This wisdom Library page is indicating that the consort of Narasimha Avatara of Lord vishnu is an aspect of goddess Laxami called as **Vidyuta.**

---

> Nṛsiṃha (नृसिंह, “Man-lion form”):—One of the twenty-four forms of
>   Viṣṇu through which Nārāyaṇa manifests himself. The meaning of this
>   title is “The one who assumes the celestial man-lion form”. **He is
>   accompanied by a counterpart emanation of Lakṣmī (an aspect of Devī)
>   who goes by the name Vidyutā.**

---

**[Vidyutā (विद्युता, “flashing, glittering”)](https://www.wisdomlib.org/definition/vidyuta)**:—One of the twenty-four emanations of Lakṣmī accompanying Nārāyaṇa. This particular manifestation couples with his counterpart form called Nṛsiṃha and together they form the twenty-first celestial couple. Lakṣmī represents a form of the Goddess (Devī) as the wife of Viṣṇu, while Nārāyaṇa represents the personification of his creative energy, according to the Pāñcarātra literature.

Answer (score -1):

The lord is always accompanied by his energies. In Hinduism (in other religions too) the supreme lord accompanied by his female counterpart is always very prominent and as Lord Narsingh Dev is Vishnu's expansion His consort is Lakshmi.

Comment: The question was to provide the name of his consort, essentially she would be an avatar of Lakshmi, but she would have a different name and appearance (given that there was one)

Comment: Answers on this site should be backed with with proper sources. Visit [Guidelines for new users answering questions](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/125/3500)